GLM dispersion based on Pearson residuals
In R's glm, the dispersion parameter can be automatically derived using a quasilikelihood model. When I manually compute it, the values are slightly different. The difference is very small and will not affect data analysis, but I want to check if there is something wrong with the way the dispersion is manually computed.
n <- 20
nsim <- 1000
out <- matrix(NA,nsim,2)

for(i in 1:nsim){
x <- runif(n,0,10)
y <- rpois(n,exp(0.1+0.1*x))
model <- glm(y~x,family=poisson)
out[i,1] <- sum(residuals(model,type="pearson")^2)/(n-2)
out[i,2] <- summary(glm(y~x,family=quasipoisson))$dispersion
}

plot(out[,1]-out[,2])



Interesting!  When I run your code and compare the two columns of out, I get a correlation of 1 and a difference between means in the 7th decimal place.  Consequently, I suspect it is due to finite precision errors accumulating differently between the two algorithms used to calculate dispersion.
